# Absolute positioning causes React Native component to go off screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, frontend

One of my React Native screens needs to have a TouchableOpacity at the bottom of the screen. I've tried setting `position: "absolute"` and `bottom: 0`, however, this just causes the element to be a few hundred pixels below the screen. How can I make my TouchableOpacity be at the bottom of the screen all the time?

```
    <View style={styles.mainView}>
                    <View style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cartView}>
                                <Text style={styles.cartText}>View cart</Text>
                            </ViewTouchableOpacity
                    </View>
                }
            />
        </View>

    //styles
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        mainView: {
// devDims are the device dimensions
            minHeight: devDims.height,
            minWidth: devDims.width,
            backgroundColor: "white",
            paddingLeft: 10,
            paddingRight: 10,
            paddingTop: 10,
        },
        cartView: {
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            maxHeight: 50,
            minWidth: "100%",
            alignSelf: "center",
            marginTop: 50,
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 20,
        },
        cartText: {
            fontFamily: "semi",
            fontSize: 22,
        },
    });
```

Comment: you probably want `postion: fixed` as that fixes the postion to the screen rather than the document (which is what absolute is doing)

Answer (score 2):

We could handle this without absolute positioning using `flex` alone.

Add `flex:1` to the parent view and to the view that wraps the sticky bottom. Then, add `flex: 2` to the view that wraps the other content.

Here is a minimal generic component that lets you add a sticky bottom component.

```js
const MainScreen = ({bottom, children}) => {
   return <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
            {children}
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
          {bottom}
        </View>
    </View>
}

export default function App() {
  return <MainScreen bottom={
             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cartView}>
                <Text style={styles.cartText}>View cart</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>}> 
    </MainScreen>
}
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]

However, we can use `absolute` positioning as well. You are just missing the `flex: 1` for the parent view.

```js
export default function App() {
  return <View style={styles.mainView}>
                    <View style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0 }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cartView}>
                                <Text style={styles.cartText}>View cart</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
        </View>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        mainView: {
          flex: 1,
// devDims are the device dimensions
            minHeight: devDims.height,
            minWidth: devDims.width,
            backgroundColor: "red",
            paddingLeft: 10,
            paddingRight: 10,
            paddingTop: 10,
        },
        cartView: {
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            maxHeight: 50,
            minWidth: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            alignSelf: "center",
            marginTop: 50,
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 20,
        },
        cartText: {
            fontFamily: "semi",
            fontSize: 22,
        },
    });
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `position` as `absolute` then your view must be last view before last closed view tag

When you have declared any view at bottom of the screen then you should be do like this

```
import {View, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<!---Anything extra views---!>
<View style={{bottom:0,position:'absolute',start:0,end:0}}> !-- you're bottom view

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.cartView}>
<Text style={styles.cartText}>View cart</Text>
</ViewTouchableOpacity

</View>
</View>
</SafeAreaView >
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used position absolute to style the TouchableOpacity, so wrapping the TouchableOpacity with a View and then giving the position absolute to it solved the problem.

before :

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={goBack} style={styles.backButtonContainer}>
     <Image style={styles.backButton} source={require("../../assets/back.png")} />
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

after :

```
   <View style={styles.backButtonContainer}>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={goBack} >
              <Image style={styles.backButton} source={require("../../assets/back.png")} />
         </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

the style :

```
    backButtonContainer: {
        position: "absolute",
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        top: 5,
        left: 5,
    },
```